# CMD.exe How to create INI filelist with CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ini

how to create INI file of file list with cmd?

eg. 
This will create print list of all txt files...

```
dir /b *.txt > FileList.log
```

---

```
Readme.txt
Info.txt
Data.txt
```

but how to create INI filelist of all *.txt files in directory with cmd?

```
[Uninstall]
file1=Readme.txt
file2=Info.txt
file3=Data.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
@echo [Uninstall] > FileList.log
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a counter=0
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
  set /a counter=!counter!+1
  echo file!counter!=%%i >> FileList.log
)
```

Comment: Why are you taking the first token in a space delimited string?  If the filenames contain spaces then it will truncate the filename.

Comment: @foxidrive Good point, to be honest I haven't used batch-scripts in a long time and just adapted an old script I already had. It seemed to work so I didn't think more about it. Removing the tokens part would indeed be good. There's probably other stuff there that can be improved too, like the use of @ signs.

Comment: I edited the tokens out and replaced it with `delims=` which is all it needed.